# Collision Detection in libgdx

Tags: java, libgdx, collision

My question is mostly related to the theory behind it. I make a 2D game for a project and i detect collisions by using the .overlaps method in the Rectangle class and the collisions are handled beautifully. First of all , is that considered to be a continuous or discrete collision technique. As i'm reading the theory i say it is discrete ,however i'm reading in online articles that the major disadvantage of discrete is that it detects collision after it actually happened. So,my question is the following : is it actually discrete and if it is why i see no disadvantages? 
Thanks

Comment: It is discrete because you update the positions in timesteps, it just happens so fast the human eye cannot see it, if you lower the fps you will notice how discontinuous the movements really are. Unless you can  actually see or notice this there is no point in worrying about it. Continuous collisiondetection uses prediction (interpolation) to turn objects away before they collide.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is discreet because we only know if two bounding boxes collided after we check if the imaginary/invisible boxes intersected meaning they already overlapped. So by the time you take action (update) due to that collision, the objects are not in the collided position. Worse case, if they are not in **relative speed**, they can pass through. Think of the classic helicopter game where you dodge obstacles by going up and down. Say you put the velocity of the chopper on x really high, depending on your frame rate which depends on the hardware, you will see different positions of actual collision. For continuous, one object has to be aware of the physics properties of the other objects it may collide with to **predict** possible collision.

In reality, for 2d games like the helicopter game I mentioned, it really doesn't matter much. You can **simulate** the result of the collision by doing changes on an object's rotation, velocity, gravity and through some nice animations. If your game objects have abstract shapes, you should use something like box2d. There's a good [**Intersector**](http://libgdx.badlogicgames.com/nightlies/docs/api/com/badlogic/gdx/math/Intersector.html) class as well.

Also, you can experiment with different bounding box sizes (bounds) of an object rather than creating the bounding box of the object equal to its width and height.